# How to stop multiple tabs opening in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

multiple(2) new tabs are opening and closing after  I have clicked download button in my application.
Expected output:when I want to click on **downlolad testfile button** test file should open in newtab.
but it was opening in 2 mutiple tabs.

Comment: It would help to see your code

Comment: maybe it's a `<a>` to the file, with some JS attached which also opens a new window? Edit your question and post some code

Answer (score 0):

Check your target attributes on the download link.